# Issue loading correct orientation UIView on load using one xib

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, xib

I have a xib file with two different views, one for portrait and one for landscape.

In my .m file I have the following:

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

{
if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
{

self.view = iPadLandscape;
}
else {

self.view = iPadPortrait;
}
}
```

When the app is running that specific screen and I change orientation the new view loads fine. There are two issues that I have noticed though. The "view" for the xib is connected to the portrait view. So when the app launches in portrait it looks fine but if launched in landscape orientation it still loads the portrait view. But if I move it to portrait and back the landscape view loads fine.

The other problem is if, say, I launch in portrait and go to next screen, then change to landscape mode (rotates fine), then go back to my main screen it'll still be in portrait view.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

Check explicitly for the current orientation in viewWillAppear too and update you view.

As willRotateToOrientation is not called on application load and many other events

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  NSUInteger orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
  switch (orientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
      // self.view == my landscape view
      break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
      // self.view == my portrait view
      break;
  }
}
```